# Как добавить ajax в Sinatra и will_paginate?

Tags: ajax, ruby, sinatra

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь прикрутить ajax к Sinatra и гему will_paginate. Will_paginate без ajax работает отлично. Вместе - пока не очень: при рендере страницы с данными подтягивается общий шаблон и дублируется верхнее меню и заголовок.

Так у меня выглядит layout.slim

```
doctype 5
html lang="en"
  head
    meta charset="utf-8"
    title = SITE_NAME
    link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.min.css"
body
  .container
    == yield
```

Так index.slim

```
.top-menu
  ul.nav.nav-pills.navbar-right
    li ...
.row
  .col-xs-12
    h1 Payments
    #payments
      == slim :content
```

Так content.slim

```
.table-responsive
  table.table.table-bordered.table-striped
    thead
      tr.active
        <...some code...>
    tbody
      - @payments.each do | payment |
        <...some code...>
== will_paginate(@payments)
```

В main.js добавил следующий код:

```
$(".pagination a").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $(this).attr("href"),
    success:function(result) {
      $("#payments").html(result);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Понимаю, что нужно как-то отключить layout у content.slim, но как это сделать в данном случае - не пойму.

Comment: а как вы json/js отдаёте с сервера?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, не очень хорошо знаком с синатрой. Но видимо, в контроллере сделать что-то типа

```
slim :content, layout: false
```

http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#partials